# MALFORMED_ID Error during integration

Tags: custom-object, integration, externalid, field-mapping

We have a custom object called "Activity" with 2 lookup fields and an external ID.
The 2 lookup fields are Contact and Course.

1. The Contact object contains "contact ID" as the external ID (lookup on the Activity record called Volunteer).
2. The Course object contains "course ID" as the external ID (lookup on the Activity record called Course).
3. The Activity external ID is the contactID+courseID.

I have created an integration mapping to all 3 fields listed above. I keep getting the following error:
Error loading into target [Activity__c] : Error received from salesforce.com. Fields [Volunteer__c]. Status code [MALFORMED_ID]. Message [Volunteer: id value of incorrect type: T012919].

I know for a fact that the ID "T012919" is what is used as one of three external IDs on the Contact object ("contact ID" as the external ID).

What's frustrating is we have another integration that has a lookup to the contact object and we are able to successfully map the lookup field to the contact object (using a different external ID).

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by _integration mapping_. Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Help Center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for guidance.

Comment: @user78286 - If I understood the scenario correctly, Activity.Activity__c is causing the issue. The reason for the same is formula of Activity__c is - contactId + activityId. This would give you the combination of the salesforce record Ids, not their actual values. 

So your Activity.Activity__c is expecting values like - 003123456789012a01123456789012 and your integration system is sending values like T012919 assuming that T01 is contact ID and 919 is course ID (functionally).

Comment: @YsrShk This makes sense but what is the workaround? We have integrations where we feed IDs into "lookup" fields and it works fine. I'm confused why this would be an issue now.

Comment: @user78286 - Update your formula in `Activity.Activity__c` with the actual names, and most likely it should solve the issue.  Sample formula would look something like this (use your API names or use insert field OOTB way) - `Contact_Id__r.Name+Course_Id__r.Name`